# Codeigniter weird database error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Everytime I insert a new data it will say that `post_id` cannot be `NULL` but when I check phpmyadmin. The correct id is stored.

I'm using ajax to send the `id's` from the view to the controller. I've tried `alert(id)` to see if the `id` is really selected and it is selected so no problem in the jquery part.

It works the way I want it to, it's just that there is this error which does not really stop the insertion and I can hide the error but I would like to fix it without using that.

jquery

```
var post_id = $(this).closest('.portlet').find('.form').find('.postid').val();
        var comment = $(this).closest('.comments').find('textarea').val();
        alert("This is the post id "+post_id+"\nThis is the comment "+comment);
        $(this).closest('.comments').submit();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: BASE_URL+'classes/addcomment',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {post_id: post_id, comment: comment},
            async: false
    });
```

In the alert, I can see the id and the comments and they are correct. So I'm pretty sure there is no problem in accessing.

controller

```
public function addcomment(){
        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'post_id' => $this->input->post('post_id'),
            'content' => $this->input->post('comment')
        );
        $this->Comment_model->addcomment($data);
        redirect('/classes/ICT141');
    }
```

the error

```
Error Number: 1048
Column 'post_id' cannot be null
INSERT INTO `post_comments` (`user_id`, `post_id`, `content`) VALUES ('4', NULL, NULL)
Line Number: 28
```

Line number 28 in the model is just

```
public function addcomment($data){ 
    $this->db->insert('post_comments', $data);
   }
```

Comment: can you post your code???

Comment: jquery and controller codes added. sorry for the late edit

Comment: also post model code and what is `$this->user_id,` in your code??

Comment: it's just form a session

Comment: i've added the error and there is no problem with the `user_id`. No problem in accessing the id and the comment (proven by the alert box).

Comment: Need to confirm what is actually sent ... do a dump of `$_POST` . In JS show what `$(this)` is and show html structure.... best bet is traverses are wrong to get the values. You can also see exactly what is sent by inspecting the request in browser dev tools network

Comment: figured it out already. i just overlooked somethings lol. this is embarassing

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to :

```
var post_id = $(this).closest('.portlet').find('.form').find('.postid').val();
        var comment = $(this).closest('.comments').find('textarea').val();
        alert("This is the post id "+post_id+"\nThis is the comment "+comment);
        $(this).closest('.comments').submit();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: BASE_URL+'classes/addcomment',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"post_id" : post_id, "comment" : comment},
            async: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in phpmyadmin try setting the Default value for post_id